# Please say what should be done with this answer

Tags: discussion

[Beispiele für Konsonanten, die zwischen Artikel und Wort gewandert sind](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/811/beispiele-fur-konsonanten-die-zwischen-artikel-und-wort-gewandert-sind/817#817)

Burbuja writes in answer to my question "I would see this as total nonsense.".

After my comment question what it is s/he sees as total nonsense and to fix the wrong orthography of "Etymologie" as "Ethymologie", s/he writes an answering comment that ignores the question about the nonsense and links to an empty site about "Enthymologie" to prove that I am wrong.

So, I don't see a way to communicate with this user and don't know what to do about this.

Comment: I'd say don't waste your energy on him - but I'd be impressed if you can get him to argue that he's a throll.

Comment: @misterben: You answer is very impressive.

Comment: i'd call for a mod. so flag it. and please stay as polite as possible, never argue somebody into being a throll, that will ping back to the community as a whole :(

Comment: Can you please search for a more meaningful title for your question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a problem. The voting process will show both of you what the community thinks.

If you find the comment offensive (which I don't), then flag it.

Comment: If I write ofensive, you say that this is wrong and in response I link to http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offennsive will your main concern be whether my response is offensive?

Comment: @thei: No, I wrote that in case you were concerned about "ich kann das Wort richtig schreiben". My point is that there is a mechanism for handling wrong answers: downvoting.

Comment: You can't vote down comments.

Comment: @thei: Upvoting a contradicting comment is practically the same.

Comment: Case in point I just upvoted your comment. ;) Additionally when there are a lot of comments, the comments with fewer votes are hidden by default and have to be opened manually. This makes it easy to skim the discussion and go in deeper if it doesn't make sense without the hidden comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's no big problem. It seems to attract a lot of down votes. I'm beginning to get curious if burbuja stands the pressure and keeps his highly down voted answer or if he deletes it.